# Python - non-English characters don't work in one case

Tags: python, utf-8, character, non-english

Despite the fact I tried to find a solution to my problem both on english and my native-language sites I was unable to find a solution.
I'm querying an online dictionary to get translated words, however non-English characters are displayed as e.g. `x86` or `x84`. However, if I just do `print(the_same_non-english_character)` the letter is displayed in a proper form. I use Python 3.3.2 and the HTML source of the site I extract the words from has `charset=UTF-8` set. 
Morever, if I use e.g. `replace("x86", "non-english_character")`, I don't get anything replaced, but replacing of normal characters works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape with a `\`:

```
In [1]: s= "\x86"

In [2]:  s.replace("\x86","non-english_character")
Out[2]: 'non-english_character'
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. Actually I mistyped the initial output - firstly it printed e.g. `\xc4\x85` instead of `ą` and what helped was `replace(\\xc4\\xc5)` - so it was printed with slash in the first place and in replace I just added one more before `xc4` and before `x85`, so it finally prints `ą`

Comment: But I'm still wondering about how my "solution" is effective. I have to do similar replace function for every non-english character, isn't there a more elegant way to avoid outputs lik/x86/x85 ? Like changing some settings?

Comment: so you get `\xc4\x85` as output? Might help if you added the code and the site

Comment: what does `"\xc4\x85".encode("latin-1").decode()` output

Comment: I will try to add the code and try your other suggestions later but for now, could you tell me if such a program that extract some data from HTML source code of a given website is acceptable for commercial use i.e. if it's legal to make money from it? Technically, such HTML source file is available to everyone, the program just speeds up the process. Just curious.